# Is there a way to reference backspace in python with pynput?

Tags: python, pynput

Hi everyone I want to know if there is any way to reference backspace for my project, I want to do if the person presses 'a' then it deletes it and types 'ree' can someone pls help me with this?

Code:

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

COMBINATIONS = [
    {keyboard.KeyCode(char='a')}
]

current = set()

def execute():
    keyboard = Controller()
    if keyboard.on_press('a'):
        *insert code here*
    keyboard.type('ree')

def on_press(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.add(key)
        if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
            execute()


def on_release(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.remove(key)

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: The `Controller` object does not have an `on_press` method.

Answer (score 1):

To overwrite a letter, you can send the `'\b'` which will move the cursor backwards one letter.  Subsequent letters will then write over it.

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, Controller
from pynput import keyboard

key_ctrl = Controller()

def on_press(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        return False
    elif key == keyboard.KeyCode.from_char('a'):
        key_ctrl.type('\bree')

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: I created a Pastebin to show you the code because StackOverflow won't allow that many characters, anyways here's the problem
https://pastebin.com/QmVAyA97

Comment: Sorry. I dropped one of the import statements.  Try it now.  Also, it seems to not work on the first 'a', but only subsequent ones for me.